# Is it possible to sort letters automatically in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

Is it possible to sort letters automatically in Thunderbird?

I need to put certain topics into specific folders. Is it possible to program Thunderbird to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your messages are defined by topic. If a sender, receiver, or part of the subject line can be used to define the topic, you can set up message filters: see http://en.flossmanuals.net/thunderbird/filters/ for a few screenshots explaining how to do this. Or the addon http://mesquilla.com/extensions/filtaquilla/ can give you more options for how to set up the filter, including regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it a lot easier, [install my addon quickFilters](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quickfilters/). You can set it up to start up automatically and suggest adding a new filter whenever you move an email. It also prefills the filter action and conditions depending on a selected template. I guarantee this is the fastest way to create new filters. (drag-click-click or click-click-click if the mail was already moved to the new location).

hth,

Axel